# Count the segments where a[i] is rightmost or leftmost and is max

Tags: algorithm

You are given an array containing `N` integers and you have to answer `K` queries. Each query contains an integer `X` which is the index of the (1 based index) element of the array.
Calculate the following for each query:

```
The number of segments containing the index X as the leftmost or the 
rightmost element and the number at the index `X` is `>=` each element
of that segment.
```

Segment formation example:
You have array `{1, 2, 3}`.
The possible segments for `3` are `[2,3]` and `[1,2,3]` and `[3]`.
The possible segments for 2 are `[2]` and `[1,2]`
I got solution by brute force. Worst case Time Complexity is `O(n * k)`

```
Input: Array[] = {4,2,1,3}, Queries[] = {1,4}
Output:  
4  
3

Explanation: 
For first query 1 all possible valid segments are [4], [4,2] , [4,2,1] and [4,2,1,3] 
hence answer is 4.  
For second query 4 all possible valid segments are [3], [1,3] and [2,1,3]
hence answer is 3.
```

Comment: Please reconsider your question and take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
This board is about helping others with their coding-problems. What have you done so far? Please show us the codelines you have written so far concerning the problem. If you have errors or warnings please show them to us as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's focus on leftmost because rightmost is the mirror image.

For each `X`, we equivalently want to count how many consecutive entries after `a[X]` are less than or equal to `a[X]`. There's a trick to do this with a stack in linear time. We scan the array left to right and use the stack to remember which `X`s are still accumulating elements. The key property is that the `a` values corresponding to the stack elements will be nondecreasing, hence once the element on top of the stack isn't done yet, none of the elements under it will be either.

For example, suppose that the input is

```
  X : 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
a[X]: 3,1,4,1,5,9,2,6
```

Scan the array left to right.

```
stack is initially empty
a[1] = 3
push 1, stack is 1
a[2] = 1
don't pop 1 since a[1] = 3 ≥ 1 = a[2]
push 2, stack is 1,2
a[3] = 4
pop 2 since a[2] = 1 < 4 = a[3]; the answer for X=2 is 3 - 2 = 1
pop 1 since a[1] = 3 < 4 = a[3]; the answer for X=1 is 3 - 1 = 2
push 3, stack is 3
a[4] = 1
don't pop 3 since a[3] = 4 ≥ 1 = a[4]
push 4, stack is 3,4
a[5] = 5
pop 4 since a[4] = 1 < 5 = a[5]; the answer for X=4 is 5 - 4 = 1
pop 3 since a[3] = 4 < 5 = a[5]; the answer for X=3 is 5 - 3 = 2
push 5, stack is 5
a[6] = 9
pop 5 since a[5] = 5 < 9 = a[6]; the answer for X=5 is 6 - 5 = 1
push 6, stack is 6
a[7] = 2
don't pop 6 since a[6] = 9 ≥ 2 = a[7]
push 7, stack is 6,7
a[8] = 6
pop 7 since a[7] = 2 < 6 = a[8]; the answer for X=7 is 8 - 7 = 1
don't pop 6 since a[6] = 9 ≥ 6 = a[8]
push 8, stack is 6,8
```

Then at the end we pop everything left.

```
pop 8; the answer for X=8 is 9 - 8 = 1
pop 6; the answer for X=6 is 9 - 6 = 3
```

In Python:

```
def rightward(lst):
    counts = [0] * len(lst)
    stack = []
    for i, x in enumerate(lst):
        while stack and lst[stack[-1]] < x:
            counts[stack[-1]] = i - stack[-1]
            del stack[-1]
        stack.append(i)
    while stack:
        counts[stack[-1]] = len(lst) - stack[-1]
        del stack[-1]
    return counts


def intervals(lst):
    return list(map(lambda l, r: l + r - 1, rightward(lst[::-1])[::-1], rightward(lst)))


print(intervals([3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6]))
```

Comment: Can you give an pseudocode or program for it

Comment: I closed this question but I'm a little confused because the text for both questions seems identical! Perhaps there are better answers here? Feel free to review/alter my closing action.

Answer (score 1):

Let me describe only the solution for the segments, where X is rightmost, the solution where X is leftmost everything is the same but reversed.

I would use `a[i]` as the value in array at position `i`, and `r[i]` as the index, where longest segment ending with index `i` with `X >= each element` starts. First, several observations:

```
r[0] = 0
r[i] = i if a[i] < a[i - 1]
r[i] <= r[i - 1] otherwise
```

The first observation is obvious, the second one is correct, because the segment of length of at least two would have `a[i - 1]` inside it and break the condition, while the segment of length one is always possible. The third observation is correct because if every element `a[r[i - 1], i - 1] <= a[i - 1] <= a[i]`.

Now the last observation, if we already know that `r[i] <= r[i - 1]`, there are two cases, either `a[r[i - 1] - 1] <= a[i]`, or `a[r[i - 1] - 1] > a[i]`. If the first is true, then, applying transitivity one more time, we can say that `r[i] <= r[r[i - 1] - 1]`, if the second is true, then `r[i] = r[i - 1]`.

With these observations, the solution would be as follows (written in pseudocode):

```
r[0] = 0
for i = 1 to N do
  r[i] = i
  while r[i] > 0 do
    if a[r[i] - 1] > a[i] then break
    else r[i] = r[r[i] - 1]
  end
end
```

The number of segments with the rightmost index `i` would be `i - r[i]`. Do the same solution for leftmost indices (going from the end to the beginning), and these results up. Note that it would sound segment `[i, i]` twice, so you also should subtract one.

Now let me show why this solution is linear-time. Because all segments are nested, if we ever add one segment to another through the inner while loop, we would never use it again, we would use the bigger segment it was added to. So each segment would be once created, and no more than once used, thus, the total time would be `O(N)`.